# Using case doesnt show overlapping results when 2 promotions have the same start date (SQL Snowflake)

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
with cte as (
    select
        count(distinct o.consumers),
        max(first_order_flag) as first_order_flag,
        date(order_created_date) as date,
        case
        when order_created_date between '2023-01-01' and '2023-01-14' then 'Promo1'
        when order_created_date between '2023-01-01' and '2023-01-21' then 'Promo2'
        else '0'
        end as promotion
    from orders
    group by o.consumers, order_created_date
)

select
    promotion,
    min(date(date)),
    max(date(date)),
    sum(case when first_order_flag = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as new_consumers,
    sum(case when first_order_flag = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as returning_consumers
from cte 
group by promotion;
```

The results show that promo2 min date starts from the 14th instead of the 1st.
When I asked GPT why, it said it was because the start dates are the same, so the promo2 automatically left off after the end of promo1.
I want promo2 to show from the 1st (results of promo1 + the other days)

Changing the order of the cases just removes the first promo completely from the results and only shows promo2 (this time from the 1st)

I just want both promos, both showing results from the 1st.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you have two columns for promotion itself. The way the code is written, it won't check for promo2 if the date falls before 14th.
My suggestion would be to have two separate columns and apply your logic accordingly.

```
with cte as (
    select
        count(distinct o.consumers)
        ,max(first_order_flag) as first_order_flag,
        ,date(order_created_date) as date_,
        ,case when date(order_created_date) between '2023-01-01' and '2023-01-14' then 'Promo1' else 0 end as promotion1
        ,case when date(order_created_date) between '2023-01-01' and '2023-01-21' then 'Promo2' else 0 end as promotion2
    from orders o
    group by o.consumers, order_created_date
)

select
    promotion1
    ,promotion2
    ,min(date_) as min_date
    ,max(date_) as max_date
    ,sum(case when first_order_flag = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as new_consumers
    ,sum(case when first_order_flag = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as returning_consumers
from cte 
group by promotion1,promotion2;
```

I haven't tested this code. But hope it helps you.

Please let me know on how you are expecting the output so that I can align with your thinking.